# How to set drawable on an imageview using rxjava and rxandroid

Tags: java, android

I am able to use text using rxjava and rxandroid in my code using Textview. Now i m thinking of replacing the textview with imageview and displaying the drawable on the imageview. But I m getting errors. Since, I m new to rxjava, I m probably sure that I m missing something. An help would be really gr8!

Since to show a text, we used the parameter as String...So I thought for a drawable, I thought I might need the parameter as a Drawable...But its giving error..

```
package com.prajwal.rxjava_rxandroid;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;


import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView textView;
    Observable<Integer> stringObservable;
    DisposableObserver<Drawable> disposableObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        stringObservable = Observable.just(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);


disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Drawable drawable) {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(drawable).into(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};

        stringObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(disposableObserver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disposableObserver.dispose();
    }
}
```

Error: Cannot resolve method subscribe(Drawable)

Answer (score 1):

Find out the solution:

```
package com.prajwal.rxjava_rxandroid;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;


import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView textView;
    Observable<Integer> stringObservable;
    DisposableObserver<Integer> disposableObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        stringObservable = Observable.just(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);


/*
        stringObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                textView.setText(s); //emitted data is set to textview.
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
*/

    disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(integer).asBitmap().into(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};

        stringObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(disposableObserver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        disposableObserver.dispose();
    }
}
```

> I was passing the parameter as Drawable whereas I needed to pass the
>   parameter as an Integer since .load() of Glide doesnt take Drawable as
>   a parameter.